# Print a ReportViewer Without Preview

Tags: c#, mysql, reportviewer

I'm using Visual Studio 2010  C# Windows Forms Application + MySql
I have a Report Viewer that is working 100% . The reportviewer is filled with data of my database, it shows up I click on the button to print and it prints... BUT, my client does not want to click on this button, he wants to print automatically. When I Call the ReportViewer it print by itself without need to click on a button to do that. Could anyone tell me how I do that ?

I tryed reportviewer1.print and the PrintDocument from the toolbox. But I do not know how to use these correctly.

Thanks the attention !

Comment: Is this using CrystalReports?  That's the only Report Viewer I know, but that doesn't mean it's the only one.

Comment: No, its ReportViewer ( Just 'Report' from the ToolBox ) Could you give a shot and tell me how to do this? Maybe its not so different =)

Answer (score 8):

I had just the same issue this is the code i use and works like a charm!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace NewLabelPrinter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ReportPrintDocument will print all of the pages of a ServerReport or LocalReport.
    /// The pages are rendered when the print document is constructed.  Once constructed,
    /// call Print() on this class to begin printing.
    /// </summary>
    class AutoPrintCls : PrintDocument
    {
        private PageSettings m_pageSettings;
        private int m_currentPage;
        private List<Stream> m_pages = new List<Stream>();

        public AutoPrintCls(ServerReport serverReport)
            : this((Report)serverReport)
        {
            RenderAllServerReportPages(serverReport);
        }

        public AutoPrintCls(LocalReport localReport)
            : this((Report)localReport)
        {
            RenderAllLocalReportPages(localReport);
        }

        private AutoPrintCls(Report report)
        {
            // Set the page settings to the default defined in the report
            ReportPageSettings reportPageSettings = report.GetDefaultPageSettings();

            // The page settings object will use the default printer unless
            // PageSettings.PrinterSettings is changed.  This assumes there
            // is a default printer.
            m_pageSettings = new PageSettings();
            m_pageSettings.PaperSize = reportPageSettings.PaperSize;
            m_pageSettings.Margins = reportPageSettings.Margins;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);

            if (disposing)
            {
                foreach (Stream s in m_pages)
                {
                    s.Dispose();
                }

                m_pages.Clear();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnBeginPrint(PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnBeginPrint(e);

            m_currentPage = 0;
        }

        protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPrintPage(e);

            Stream pageToPrint = m_pages[m_currentPage];
            pageToPrint.Position = 0;

            // Load each page into a Metafile to draw it.
            using (Metafile pageMetaFile = new Metafile(pageToPrint))
            {
                Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                        e.PageBounds.Left - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                        e.PageBounds.Top - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                        e.PageBounds.Width,
                        e.PageBounds.Height);

                // Draw a white background for the report
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

                // Draw the report content
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageMetaFile, adjustedRect);

                // Prepare for next page.  Make sure we haven't hit the end.
                m_currentPage++;
                e.HasMorePages = m_currentPage < m_pages.Count;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnQueryPageSettings(QueryPageSettingsEventArgs e)
        {
            e.PageSettings = (PageSettings)m_pageSettings.Clone();
        }

        private void RenderAllServerReportPages(ServerReport serverReport)
        {
            try
            {
                string deviceInfo = CreateEMFDeviceInfo();

                // Generating Image renderer pages one at a time can be expensive.  In order
                // to generate page 2, the server would need to recalculate page 1 and throw it
                // away.  Using PersistStreams causes the server to generate all the pages in
                // the background but return as soon as page 1 is complete.
                NameValueCollection firstPageParameters = new NameValueCollection();
                firstPageParameters.Add("rs:PersistStreams", "True");

                // GetNextStream returns the next page in the sequence from the background process
                // started by PersistStreams.
                NameValueCollection nonFirstPageParameters = new NameValueCollection();
                nonFirstPageParameters.Add("rs:GetNextStream", "True");

                string mimeType;
                string fileExtension;


                Stream pageStream = serverReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, firstPageParameters, out mimeType, out fileExtension);



                // The server returns an empty stream when moving beyond the last page.
                while (pageStream.Length > 0)
                {
                    m_pages.Add(pageStream);

                    pageStream = serverReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, nonFirstPageParameters, out mimeType, out fileExtension);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("possible missing information ::  " + e);
            }
        }

        private void RenderAllLocalReportPages(LocalReport localReport)
        {
            try
            {
                string deviceInfo = CreateEMFDeviceInfo();

                Warning[] warnings;

                localReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, LocalReportCreateStreamCallback, out warnings);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error :: " + e);
            }
        }

        private Stream LocalReportCreateStreamCallback(
            string name,
            string extension,
            Encoding encoding,
            string mimeType,
            bool willSeek)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            m_pages.Add(stream);

            return stream;
        }

        private string CreateEMFDeviceInfo()
        {
            PaperSize paperSize = m_pageSettings.PaperSize;
            Margins margins = m_pageSettings.Margins;

            // The device info string defines the page range to print as well as the size of the page.
            // A start and end page of 0 means generate all pages.
            return string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>emf</OutputFormat><StartPage>0</StartPage><EndPage>0</EndPage><MarginTop>{0}</MarginTop><MarginLeft>{1}</MarginLeft><MarginRight>{2}</MarginRight><MarginBottom>{3}</MarginBottom><PageHeight>{4}</PageHeight><PageWidth>{5}</PageWidth></DeviceInfo>",
                ToInches(margins.Top),
                ToInches(margins.Left),
                ToInches(margins.Right),
                ToInches(margins.Bottom),
                ToInches(paperSize.Height),
                ToInches(paperSize.Width));
        }

        private static string ToInches(int hundrethsOfInch)
        {
            double inches = hundrethsOfInch / 100.0;
            return inches.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";
        }
    }
}
```

This class has the set up perfect for what you need then all you need to do is:

```
private void AutoPrint()
    {
        AutoPrintCls autoprintme = new AutoPrintCls(reportViewer1.LocalReport);
        autoprintme.Print();
    }
```

and hey presto it prints. Just attach this to A method in your code(maybe after the report Loads.) and your setup nicely!

option: (not tested)

As spotted this prints out to the default printer, to change the printer you could do the following:

```
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    m_pageSettings .PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
}
```

not tested though as i no longer have any source code to test this out

Comment: Hi, it is possible to choose printer in your code from printdialog?

Comment: yes i believe using printdialog would suit your need, take a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfkddyc2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, but i dont know how i could give printdialog to your code...I try m_pageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;  ...but still default printer...

Comment: so you create a new printDialog - "PrintDialog pdiag = new PrintDialog();"  something like pdiag.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "myPrinterName";

actually ill update my answer

Comment: Hello. Even when setting printer to other name it still prints in default. Can you help?

Comment: PrinterSettings.PrinterName does not send the print task to specified printer. What worked for me was to set default printer before setting print task and reverting it after EndPrint. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971604/how-do-i-set-the-windows-default-printer-in-c

Answer (score 1):

If my Crystal Report answer doesn't work for you, you can also try [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2009/02/27/manually-printing-a-report.aspx).  Again, I haven't tested it, and can't be sure that it works, but it looks like an entirely different approach which might work.  If not, then I'm not going to be any help, unfortunately.

Comment: That's Ok Bobson. I Tryed something with SendKey , KeyPressing to the button "Print" that is created automatically with the ReportViewer. Do you know something about it ?

Comment: @alannaidon - I don't think I've ever used SendKey.  It sounds like a nice simple solution, though.  Feel free to add it as a new answer and accept it if you get it working.

Comment: The link provided here works very well and is completely encased in a class so you don't have to add any methods to your code, just a call to this class.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it with Crystal Reports.

```
            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            // Insert code to run the report here

            // This gets the user's default printer to print to.
            PrintDialog prt = new PrintDialog();
            rd.PrintOptions.PrinterName = prt.PrinterSettings.PrinterName; 
            // This does the printing.
            rd.PrintToPrinter(copies, true, 1, 1000);
```

I think the equivalent to `PrintOptions.PrinterName` for you would be `ReportViewer.PrinterSettings`, but I suspect what you really need is the equivalent to `PrintToPrinter()`, which I don't see in my brief look.

Comment: Really thank you for answering me  Bobson =)
I'll try it now, I dont want the PrintDialog just the print automatically, I'll try now and give a feedback as soon as possible.
I Dont have the "ReportDocument" ;s only ReportDataSource that has NO .options about 'print' ;s

Comment: @alannaidon - For you, it'd be `ReportViewer` instead of `ReportDocument`, but the idea would be the same.  If it doesn't work, try my other answer.  I suspect it's more accurate for your issue.