# directly print when using code in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, printdialog

I use the following code

```
Dim PrintR_ As Printing.PrinterSettings = ReportViewer1.PrinterSettings
PrintR_.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
ReportViewer1.PrintDialog(PrintR_)
```

However, when executed, the following form appears
[image]

All I want is not to see this screen and to print directly based on the printer's specific name

Thanks for everyone who helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print a ReportViewer Without Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734277/print-a-reportviewer-without-preview), which is in C# but won't need much effort to change to VB.NET.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not need all that
All I want is to skip the printer selection screen and print directly to the name of the predefined printer