# Print rdlc without Preview

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

Working on .rdlc to print directly (without preview) (Reference: [Print a ReportViewer Without Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734277/print-a-reportviewer-without-preview/13974568#13974568)). I am able to print directly to printer without opening ReportViewer. I am stuck in a weird situation. The above mentioned solution works well in Windows 7 but generates an error "Some parameters or credentials have not been specified" in Windows 10. This error is generated on

```
ReportPageSettings reportPageSettings = report.GetDefaultPageSettings();
```

I have tested the same code that works on Windows 7. Migrating to Windows 10 generates this error.

I have tried
1)

```
  Dim lrpt As New LocalReport()
        lrpt.ReportEmbeddedResource = "POS-Rest.Invoice.rdlc"
        Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("InvoiceDataSet", SelfDetailsBindingSource)

        lrpt.DataSources.Add(rds)
        lrpt.Refresh()
        lrpt.ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Evidence)

 Dim rpt As New ReportPrintDocument(lrpt)
rpt.Print()
```

2)

```
Dim rpt As New ReportPrintDocument(Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport)
 rpt.Print()
```

Check the error screenshot
!http://prntscr.com/nj4s49

Comment: Maybe your app isn't leveraging the user's credentials. Before you run the report try `ApplicationServices.User.InitializeWithWindowsUser()`

Comment: No Luck. I have tried to invoke the suggested method before passing my Local Report to ReportPrintDocument. But getting the same problem. Refer to Screen shots http://prntscr.com/njcph7 and http://prntscr.com/njcppz

Comment: For that exception. Could you please "View Detail". Sometimes there is an `InnerException` and sometimes the Stack Trace contains useful hints (and sometimes it doesn't).

Comment: @tgolisch InnerException is NULL. But StackTrace reveals the location ```at LocalReport.PerformBookmarkNavigation(String bookmarkis, String& uniqueName).``` Refer http://prntscr.com/njiizj