# To set default printer connected in a network using its IP address

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to set the defaultprinter using c# code,and I have tried the following and achieved the result.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object index1 = default(object);
        for (index1 = 0; (int)index1 <= PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count-1; index1 = (int)index1 + 1)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[System.Convert.ToInt32(index1)]);
        }
    }
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       a = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

       //string b = "\\192.168.0.113" + "\'" + a;
       SetDefaultPrinter(a);

    }
  [DllImport("Winspool.drv")]
    private static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string printerName);
```

The issue is am able to set printer based on its name only,but I want to set default printer using its IPaddress.How should I set the format of the parameter to be used in setdefalutprinter function to select printer using its ipaddress.Any suggestion would be of great help.Thanks in advance

It is windows stand alone application using c# vs2010 .net

Comment: try `PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printername`

Comment: did you try this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971604/how-do-i-set-the-windows-default-printer-in-c

Comment: I have used the same technique,its working fine if I use printer name ,but I want to use IP address